# Canvas aumentando a velocidade da animação a cada troca de sprite

Tags: javascript, canvas

Estou animando algumas sprites da [LPC](https://github.com/makrohn/Universal-LPC-spritesheet) em um canvas, usando Javascript. Porém, a cada vez que troco de animação, a animação começa a ficar mais rápido. O teste pode ser feito no código abaixo. Apenas aperte qualquer tecla para ele executar a animação de ataque, e veja acontecer.

Sinceramente, não consegui descobrir o problema, tentei zerar todos os objetos ao trocar a animação, mas o erro persiste

```js
var battleField;
var entities = [];

$(document).ready(function (){
 battleField = document.getElementById("duel");
 //duel.width = 64;
 //duel.height = 64;
 
 // Create sprite sheet
 var mySprite = new Image(); 
 mySprite.height = 64;
 // Create sprite
 var me = {
  state : 0,
  defaultAnim : function (){},
  render : function (){
   if(this.state === 0){
    this.defaultAnim.render();
   }
  },
  update : function (){
   if(this.state === 0){
    this.defaultAnim.update();
   }
  }
 };
 me.defaultAnim = sprite({
  context: battleField.getContext("2d"),
  width: 128,
  height: 64,
  image: mySprite,
  numberOfFrames: 2,
  ticksPerFrame: 30,
  loop: true
 });
 
 // Load sprite sheet
 mySprite.addEventListener("load", gameLoop);
 mySprite.src = "https://image.ibb.co/jmgXCb/male_white_idle.png";
 entities.push(me);
});

function sprite (options, reset) {
 var mySprite = new Image(); 
 mySprite.height = 64;
 var that = {},
  frameIndex = 0,
  tickCount = 0,
  ticksPerFrame = options.ticksPerFrame || 0,
  numberOfFrames = options.numberOfFrames || 1;
 
 that.context = options.context;
 that.width = options.width;
 that.height = options.height;
 that.image = options.image;
 that.loop = options.loop;
 
 that.update = function () {
      tickCount += 1;
      if (tickCount > ticksPerFrame) {
     tickCount = 0;
        if (frameIndex < numberOfFrames - 1) { 
          frameIndex += 1;
        } else if(that.loop) {
          frameIndex = 0;
        } else {
      that.onAnimationEnded();
     }
   }
};
 
 that.render = function () {
 
   // Clear the canvas
   that.context.clearRect(0, 0, that.width, that.height);
   
   // Draw the animation
   that.context.drawImage(
     that.image,
     frameIndex * that.width / numberOfFrames,
     0,
     that.width / numberOfFrames,
     that.height,
     0,
     0,
     that.width / numberOfFrames,
     that.height);
 };
 
 that.onAnimationEnded = function (){
  
 }
 
 return that;
}

function gameLoop () {
 
  window.requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
  for(let i = 0; i < entities.length; i++){
   var e = entities[i];
   e.render();
   e.update();
  }
}

document.onkeydown = function (){
 var mySprite = new Image(); 
 mySprite.height = 64;
 entities[0] = sprite({
  context: battleField.getContext("2d"),
  width: 260,
  height: 64,
  image: mySprite,
  numberOfFrames: 4,
  ticksPerFrame: 12 
 }, true);
 mySprite.addEventListener("load", gameLoop);
 mySprite.src = "https://image.ibb.co/eXq3JG/male_white_cast.png";
 entities[0].onAnimationEnded = function (){
  goToIdle(0);
 }
}

function goToIdle(entityIndex){
 var mySprite = new Image(); 
 mySprite.height = 64;
 mySprite.src = "https://image.ibb.co/jmgXCb/male_white_idle.png";
 // Create sprite
 entities[entityIndex] = sprite({
  context: battleField.getContext("2d"),
  width: 128,
  height: 64,
  image: mySprite,
  numberOfFrames: 2,
  ticksPerFrame: 30,
    loop: true
 });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="duel"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não precisa da linha `mySprite.addEventListener("load", gameLoop);` no `onkeydown`.

O seu gameLoop já está constantemente agendando a próxima execução. Se essa função é invocada de novo, você acaba tendo dois (ou mais) loops acontecendo em "paralelo", o que causa esse efeito de aceleração da animação.